# Thread abort in Window Service in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a window Service which converts the PDF file to html and it is running in 5 threads.
Each thread picks the record from database where status is 0.Once it picks the record from database we are making the status to 64 and making an entry in log file so that other thread should not pick the same record,after successful conversion we are making the status to 256 if any exception we are making the stratus to 128.

**Some records are updated to 64 with out any entry in log and they are not even processed further.**

Below is the Stored Procedure to pick the single record from database.

```
    Create PROCEDURE [SGZ].[p_GetNextRequestForProcessing]
    @InstanceId int
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    set nocount on

    Declare @RequestID bigint = null;

    SET @RequestID= (
                    Select 
                        TOP(1) RequestID 
                    From 
                        sgz.PDFTransformationQueue
                    Where
                        RequestStatusID=0
                );

    If (@RequestID is not null) 
    BEGIN
       Begin Transaction;
          Update 
             sgz.PDFTransformationQueue
          SET
            RequestStatusid=64,
            ProcessedInstanceID =@InstanceId,
            ProcessStartTime = getutcdate(),
            ModifiedDate=getutcdate()
         Where
            RequestID=@RequestID and
            RequestStatusid =0 and
            ProcessedInstanceID is null;

         if @@rowcount = 0
            set @RequestID=null;
    Commit Transaction;
   END

    Select 
        RQ.VersionNumber,RQ.RequestID, RP.Payload
    From
        SGZ.RequestPayload RP WITH (NOLOCK),
        SGZ.PDFTransformationQueue RQ WITH (NOLOCK)

    Where
        RP.RequestId=RQ.RequestID AND
        ProcessedInstanceID=@InstanceId AND
        RequestStatusid =64 AND
        RQ.RequestId = @RequestID;
    END
```

And below is the window service code:-

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
       {
          PDFTransAutoProcessManager pdfTransAutoProcessManager = new 
          PDFTransAutoProcessManager();
          pdfTransAutoProcessManager.OnProcessStart();
        }
```

And PDFTransAutoProcessManager class:-

```
    private int _runningAsyncThread = 0;
    private int _totalAsynThread = 5;

    public void OnProcessStart()
        {
          _logMgr.Info("Process started @ " + DateTime.Now);
           mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartAutoProcess));
           mainThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
           mainThread.Start();
        }

      private void StartAutoProcess()
       {
          try
           {
              while (true)
               {
                  if (_runningAsyncThread < _totalAsynThread)
                  {

                      Thread childThread = new Thread(() => ProcessAsync());
                      Interlocked.Increment(ref _runningAsyncThread);
                      childThread.Start();
                  }
                  Thread.Sleep(100);
              }

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          { }
      }

        private void ProcessAsync()
          {
           try
           {
              PDFGenieManager pdfGenieManager = new 
              PDFGenieManager(_logMgr,gmi);
              pdfGenieManager.ProcessRawData();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
              _logMgr.Info(ex.Message);
              _logMgr.Info(ex.StackTrace);
             }
            finally
            {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _runningAsyncThread);
            }
        }
```

And in PDFGenieManager Class actual database call and conversion will happen.
When it is trying to get records from database some records are updated to 64 with out any entry in log.

Is it related to threading pattern or any problem with stored procedure.
Kindly help thanks in advance.

Below is the PDFGenieManager class code:-

```
    namespace PDFConvertion
     {
       public class PDFGenieManager
         {
           public Logger _logMgr;
           public GmiManager _gmi;
           string _environment;
           static readonly object _object = new object();
           Dictionary<string, string> _ResourceMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public PDFGenieManager(Logger logMgr, GmiManager gmi)
    {
        _logMgr = logMgr;
        _gmi = gmi;
        _environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Envoirnment"];
    }
    public void ProcessRawData()
    {
        try
        {
            string unlockKey = string.Empty;
            string languageRepair = string.Empty;
            bool IsUnicodeRepair = false;
            double confidenceScore = 1.0;
            var Vendor = string.Empty;
            string hiddenText = string.Empty;
            DataTable rawData = new DataTable();
            RuntimeCacheMgr _runtimeCacheMgr = new RuntimeCacheMgr();

            DAL dal = new DAL();
            try
            {
                rawData = dal.GetRawData();
                if (rawData != null && rawData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    _logMgr.Info("Picked the record from datbase" + rawData.Rows[0]["Payload"].ToString());
                }
                if (!_runtimeCacheMgr.Exists(_environment))
                {
                    _ResourceMetadata = dal.getResourcemetaDataValue(_environment);
                    _runtimeCacheMgr.Add(_environment, _ResourceMetadata);
                }
                else
                {
                    _ResourceMetadata = _runtimeCacheMgr.Get<Dictionary<string, string>>(_environment);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException exe)
            {
                _logMgr.Error("Sql Database Error While Picking the records from database" + exe.Message + exe.StackTrace, exe.InnerException);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex != null && !ex.ToString().ToLower().Contains("already exist"))
                {
                    if (rawData != null && rawData.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        _logMgr.Error("Exception block Picked the record from datbase" + rawData.Rows[0]["Payload"].ToString());
                    }
                    _logMgr.Error("Exception block" + ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rawData != null && rawData.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        _logMgr.Error("Cache block Picked the record from datbase" + rawData.Rows[0]["Payload"].ToString());
                    }
                    _logMgr.Error("Cache block" + ex.Message + "" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (rawData != null && rawData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    _logMgr.Info("Finally block Picked the record from datbase" + rawData.Rows[0]["Payload"].ToString());
                }
            }
            List<PDFGenieTran> ids = new List<PDFGenieTran>(rawData.Rows.Count);
            rawData.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(row => ids.Add(new PDFGenieTran() { Payload = row["Payload"].ToString(), RequestID = Convert.ToInt64(row["RequestID"]), VersionNumber = row["VersionNumber"].ToString() }));

            PDFNetStatus PDFstatus = new PDFNetStatus();
            foreach (PDFGenieTran pdf in ids)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code in `PDFGenieManager`

Comment: I have added PDFGenieManager  class

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { }` = Bad idea!

Comment: Probably unrelated but it hurts my eye: You are creating Threads over and over. Why not reuse them? Creating Threads is expensive. I'd just create 5 Threads and move the loop into the Thread. Then I'd use an event to inform the main Thread when a child thread dies, so it can check the number of running threads to replace the dead one.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Envoirnment"];` I guess that's a typo? Env**oirn**ment?